# Getting "Unusable Erlang runtime system!" when trying to run on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: erlang, elixir, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I am compiling an elixir app on Ubuntu 18.04 in github actions and trying to run it in an Amazon Linux 2 system and I get the error "Unusable Erlang runtime system! This is likely due to being compiled for another system than the host is running"

I checked to make sure both were running on an x86_64 system and that does appear to be the case.
Github Actions Ubuntu uname: Linux fv-az21-804 5.4.0-1036-azure #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 18:26:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Amazon Linux 2 uname: Linux ip-172-10-201-177.ec2.internal 4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 16 22:44:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

OTP Version: 23.2.1
Elixir Version: 1.11.3

I am at a loss as to what could be going on.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually the case when there is a mismatch of Erlang versions.

Scenario:

- Building with [alpine-elixir:1.7.3](https://github.com/bitwalker/alpine-elixir/releases)
- Served with `alpine:latest`

Try and see if the Erlang version is consistent.

The OP asks in the comments:

> Is it possible the problem is in the `libc` mismatch between ubuntu using `glibc` and alpine using musl?

That is a possible root cause indeed. The test would be to compile it using the same libc.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  This makes sense.  I'm building it with the versions listed above but running it in alpine:latest.  I'll work on matching them. thank you!

Comment: So the versions match but it still won't work.  I think I *might* know what's going on but don't know a good way around it.  I am compiling this with ubuntu 18.04 on github actions but running it in a docker container currently with alpine:3.9  I tried running it with one of the elixir containers as well and it still gives the same error.  Is it possible the problem is in the libc mismatch between ubuntu using glibc and alpine using musl?  If so, is there any way to build the elixir app with static libraries? (something like the CGO_ENABLED flag in Go)

Comment: @user2731197 "Is it possible the problem is in the libc mismatch between ubuntu using glibc and alpine using musl?": I suspect this is the root cause. Try and compile it with the same libc.