# Github Actions and Docker Image OS mismatch

Tags: docker, elixir, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions

I am running a GitHub action on ubuntu-latest that builds a basic elixir application using distillery. However, when the image is deployed to GKE, I keep getting the error "Unusable Erlang runtime system!" and I can see that the pod is not finding a few c-related shared libraries in GKE's workloads' logs:

```
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by opt/app/erts-12.2/bin/beam.smp)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/app/erts-12.2/bin/beam.smp)
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.2/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_begin_catch: symbol not found
...
```

I have found [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731452/getting-unusable-erlang-runtime-system-when-trying-to-run-on-amazon-linux-2), which (I think) implies that this is most likely due to the GitHub action running on ubuntu, which builds the image for alpine. I have checked, and both the elixir building image and the alpine running image use the same alpine version, namely elixir:1.12-alpine and alpine:3.15. It is said on the post to "compile it with the same libc", but I have no idea how to do that. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: some libraries require additional dependencies, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011557/8103819

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!!

Comment: Hey, never mind, it somehow broke again. This time, I am getting the same "unusable erlang" error but none of the other ones.

Comment: I think maybe you miss some with erlang versions. Try to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731452/getting-unusable-erlang-runtime-system-when-trying-to-run-on-amazon-linux-2)